# Phantom flag notice in moderator tools

Tags: bug

Ever since I earned the Rep to see the moderator tools section on the "Review" screen, I have been puzzled by what I am calling "phantom" flag notices. That is, part of the screen appears to indicate that there are flags to be evaluated-- "Posts marked as requiring attention" per the link title attribute--, but when clicking the link to take a look, there are no posts. For example...

[image]

That screenshot was taken after clicking the link marked "1 flags", but clearly there are no flagged posts on the left.

I am assuming this is a bug as I can't come up with any reason to indicate that the is 1 (or more) flags needing attention when no posts actually appear on the screen.

I should add that I have voted on a few flagged posts on this screen but the great majority of times I've tried the result is as in the screenshot.

**Edit:**

Even if this is a cache related issue as suggested by Rarst, I still consider it a a bug, of bug-like, as what it accomplishes is minimization of the notice. I am basically at the point where I just ignore it.

**Edit:**

There is now a "show posts you've already flagged" link on the flag page, making this point moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't display posts that you have flagged in the flag list (however many flags by however many other people also exist on it).

However, we do display the number of flags in the tab.

Comment: Why? What’s the use case?

Comment: I will accept the answer, as it seems to be the correct one but I don't understand the logic. I don't know why I would need to be notified of a flag I can't act on and I don't why the count would display when the page itself is empty. Why not display the flagged post with a notice that "You've already flagged this post" similar to the notice you get if you attempt to "close vote" a post that you've already voted on.

Comment: @toscho - Not saying there is logic to it. There is a bug here, though it is not clear what the fix should be. My post was more about explaining the issue than anything else. You will note that I didn't `[status-*]` the question.

Answer (score 5):

"Views" and their parts on Stack Exchange are heavily cached, it often takes different parts of interface some time to catch up with data changes.

If it goes away fast (couple refreshes, under a minute) it's probably just that.

Comment: I know about the caching, and I though about that possibility, but I don't see the same behavior with the "post revision" notices that appear at the top. If that notice shows up, there actually is a revision to review about 90% or more of the time.